# Execute post-build script on the Drop folder

Tags: powershell, tfs, msbuild, nuget

I have a .NET 4 based project. It is under TFS and we have a dedicated TS build server. On check-in, by CI the TFS build server is able to checkout the solution and successfully do a build with 0 errors.
The assemblies are also all being dropped successfully to the defined drop folder on the build server.

The assemblies are dropped, but are not in the correct order/format as the application requires. As such I created a post-build Powershell script to create a new folder in the drop folder, and to move the required files from the drop folder, into this new folder.

I called the Post-build script from my build definition with the argument

```
  "$(TF_BUILD_DROPLOCATION)"
```

With this, my script is able to create a new folder on the drop folder succesfully:

```
New-Item ($droppath + "\nuget") -type directory
```

The problem now is that when I am trying to actually copy files from the drop folder to this folder, powershell is returning path/file not found error e.g.

```
Copy-Item (Join-Path $droppath "\classX") -Destination $staging -Recurse
```

or

```
Copy-Item (Join-Path $droppath "\abc.svc") -Destination $staging -Recurse
```

I know the above file exists in the drop folder, but still getting error.
My one observation is that probably the post build script is getting executed, BEFORE the files are actually dropped. Hence, my script is able to create blank folder, but the files it's trying to copy, have not got dropped yet. How can I fix this script/requirement?

Once I have all the files in place, then in the end, I will need to run nuget to package my folder via nuget, but first need to copy the correct files in this folder.

Comment: Look at the post-build example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn376353(v=vs.120).aspx#scripts) (GatherItemsForDrop.ps1). You need to set your output location to "AsConfigured", then your powershell script can arrange the files in the structure you want dropped to your staging location.

Comment: i wonder nobody have a solution on this